# Installing cypress - stuck on unzipping 0%

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, cypress, npm-install

When I run

```
npm install cypress --save-dev
```

In a Windows CMD Administrator session, I get the following output. This has been left overnight and still hangs on 0%:
[image: ouput]

If it's important, my current project dependencies are

```
"devDependencies": { "@types/react": "^17.0.0", "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0", "@types/webpack": "^4.41.25", "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7", "@types/mui-datatables": "^3.7.3", "@types/react-text-mask": "^5.4.7", "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.17.0", "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.17.0", "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0", "css-loader": "^5.0.1", "eslint": "^7.21.0", "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0", "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0", "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0", "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.5.2", "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0", "husky": "^4.3.8", "lint-staged": "^10.5.4", "prettier": "2.2.1", "style-loader": "^2.0.0", "ts-loader": "^8.0.11", "typescript": "^4.1.2", "url-loader": "^4.1.1", "webpack": "^5.9.0", "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0", "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0", "webpack-merge": "^5.4.0" }, 
"dependencies": { "@date-io/dayjs": "^1.3.13", "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.2.2", "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2", "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2", "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57", "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10", "axios": "^0.21.1", "clsx": "^1.1.1", "dayjs": "^1.10.4", "emailjs-com": "^3.1.0", "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2", "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33", "mui-datatables": "^3.7.7", "notistack": "^1.0.9", "react": "^17.0.1", "react-dom": "^17.0.1", "react-live-clock": "^5.2.0", "react-moment": "^1.1.1", "react-print-components": "^1.0.4", "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0", "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3", "text-mask-addons": "^3.8.0" }
```

Any help to identify the cause or any logs I should be looking at would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you can end it with Cntrl + c and then retry again.

Comment: Goes without saying I have tried that many times

Comment: Can you try clearing cache `cypress cache clear` and then retry installing ?

Comment: Just tried that, same issue. I even tried deleting node modules and running it. Still the same issue

Comment: UPDATE - I managed to manually download the cypress binary and extract it, I put it in the AppData folder and all good. Would still rather know why this command wouldn't work!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue when trying do a fresh npm installation for a project.
Running in the same command in an elevated window did not help.
[Jakob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7839815/jakob)'s answer helped above:

Visit https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress#Direct-download

Download the version of Cypress from https://download.cypress.io/desktop
or alternatively put the version number at the end : https://download.cypress.io/desktop/8.7.0

Extract the folder to:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\[version]
```

I ran npm install and the install completed without error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an issue that happened to me when I had a power outage during installation - so if I am right it occurs when an installation is forced down midway. I managed to solve it by deleting every cypress folder from AppData before running `npm install cypress --save-dev` .

Answer (score 1):

Unzipping manually downloaded cypress to `AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/[version]/` fixed the issue for me.

After removing cypress from the `AppData/Local` and `AppData/Roaming` if you try to run `npx cypress open` you will see:

```
Cypress executable not found at: C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.5.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe
```

So it worked after unzipping Cypress there manually.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and seemed to fix this issue by upgrading to the latest version of node and npm.

Comment: This can be added as comment, when you have enough reputation add it as comment.

Comment: Thank you, this was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yep @Rosen Mihaylov, my internet was gone mid-way, thanks! Steps I followed for the solution

1. Deleted the Cypress folder in `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Cypress\`
2. Downloaded the zip for Windows from https://download.cypress.io/desktop
3. Extracted in `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Cypress\`
4. Disabled my anti-virus
5. Did `npm install -D cypress` it took 5-10 minutes and then done (it feels like it's stuck but it's not you can check your Task Manager)
6. Run cypress by running `npx cypress open`